# Cannot install minicom on 12.0.4 LTS

Tags: apt

I cannot install minicom on 12.0.4 LTS. I get "package 'minicom' has no installation candidate' Is this because /etc/apt/sources.list is old?

Answer (score 0):

Package 'minicom' placed in 'universe' repository. Check if that repository is enabled. Your `/etc/apt/sources.list` must contain something like this:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe
```

Don't forget `sudo apt-get update` after changing the `sources.list`

Comment: Does not help. When I run "apt-get update" I see a lot of http 404's followed by "Some index files failed to download..." Then "apt-get install minicom" fails as before.

Answer (score 0):

Not all Ubuntu mirrors appear to carry the `universe` repository.
Select a different mirror via the Update Manager or Package Manager settings.

[image: Ubuntu Software settings]